# Downloading Embedded Videos

Tags: java, streaming

Youtube and other similar video sharing websites shares embedded flash videos. Many applications like Youtube Downloader realises this . I am developing a downloader using java. Can i realize this in java.

Answer (score 1):

try to look to the [java YouTube video Downloader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ytd2/?_test=b)

Answer (score 0):

definitely you can do this with java

connect url through `urlconnection`

and save read data in appropriate form for example your_Video`.mkv` etc..